# Prove $W$ is a subspace of $F$ if $W=\{\vec a \in F:a_1=\dots=a_n\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that if $F$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space and $W:=\left\{\vec a\in F:a_1=\dots=a_n\right\},$ then $W$ is a subspace of $F.$

I know that $W$ is a subspace of $F$ if it is non-empty and $\alpha \vec a+\vec b\in W$ for any scalar $\alpha$ and any $\vec a,\vec b\in W.$

Here is what I tried:

Let $\vec a_n, \vec b_n\in W$ and let $a_1=\dots=a_n=\phi$, and $b_1=\dots=b_n=\lambda.$

The subset contains $\vec 0$ since $0=\dots=0$ is true.

Now,

\begin{eqnarray}\alpha(a_1,...,a_n)+(b_1,..., b_n) &=& \alpha (a_1+ .. +a_n) + (b_1+..+ b_n)\\ &=& \alpha (\phi + ... + \phi) + (\lambda +...+ \lambda)\\ &=&
\alpha (n \phi) + (n\lambda ).\end{eqnarray} 
And therefore $W$ is a subspace of $F$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Well done.

Comment: @user247327: I'm afraid it isn't. See either of the answers below.

Comment: Alternatively, it is the kernel (or "null space") of the transformation $F\to F$ defined by $(a_1,\cdots,a_n) \mapsto (a_1-a_2,a_2-a_3,\cdots,a_{n-1}- a_n, 0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, I think. However, your notation goes a bit astray in places.

> Let $\vec a_n$, $\vec b_n$ $\in$ $W$ and let $a_1=...= a_n = \phi$, and $b_1 = ... = b_n = \lambda$.

Here, you're equivocating. It seems like you mean to suppose that $\vec a,\vec b\in W,$ which means that there are some constants $\phi,\lambda$ such that each $a_k=\phi$ and each $b_k=\lambda.$

> The subset contains $\vec 0$ since $0=..=0$ is true.

You're right, but this is a bit out of nowhere. Instead, we should **start** by saying that $\vec 0\in W.$ The reason for this is so that we can sensibly *say* things like "let $\vec a,\vec b\in W,$" because knowing that $\vec 0\in W$ is enough to show that $W\neq\emptyset.$

> Now,
>
> $$\alpha(a_1,...,a_n)+(b_1,..., b_n) = \alpha (a_1+ .. +a_n) + (b_1+..+ b_n)$$

This is not correct. The left-hand side is a vector, but the right-hand side is a scalar. Instead, we should have \begin{eqnarray}\alpha\vec a+\vec b &=& \alpha(a_1,\dots,a_n)+(b_1,\dots,b_n)\\ &=& (\alpha a_1,\dots,\alpha a_n)+(b_1,\dots, b_n)\\ &=& (\alpha a_1+b_1,\dots,\alpha a_n+b_n)\\ &=& (\alpha\phi+\lambda,\dots,\alpha\phi+\lambda)\\ &\in& W\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it should be

$\alpha (a,\ldots,a) + (b,\ldots,b) = (\alpha a + b,\ldots,\alpha a+b) = (c,\ldots,c)\in W$, where $c=\alpha a+b$.